# spacing padding not working between 2 views, with visual layout constraints?

Tags: ios, constraints, visual-format-language

I would like to add a padding between field1 and field2, it works in the storyboard, but I need to set it programmatically, so I tried this, but the 2 fields are next to each other, there is not this spacing of 30 between the two :
the container is green, the field1 is orange, the field2 is blue :

[image]

```
    var fviews = ["field1":field1, "field2":field2, "field3":field3, "field4":field4 ]
    let metrics : [NSObject: AnyObject] = ["spacingV" : 30]

    //FIELD 2 
    fviews = [ "field1":field1, "field2":field2 ]
    str = "V:|[field1]-(==spacingV)-[field2]" //----> HERE, I also tried -spacingV-
    var verticalFields = NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat(str, options: nil, metrics: metrics, views: fviews)
    self.view.addConstraints(verticalFields)

    //equal height with multiplier 0.2 :
    equalHeightMult = NSLayoutConstraint(item: field2,
        attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Height,
        relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal,
        toItem: container,
        attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Height,
        multiplier: 0.2,
        constant: 0)
    self.view.addConstraint(equalHeightMult)

    //align X center
    centerXConstraint =
        NSLayoutConstraint(item: field2,
            attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.CenterX,
            relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal,
            toItem: container,
            attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.CenterX,
            multiplier: 1.0,
            constant: 0)
    self.view.addConstraint(centerXConstraint)

    //HORIZONTAL: equal width with multiplier 0.7 :
    equalWidthMult = NSLayoutConstraint(item: field2,
        attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Width,
        relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal,
        toItem: container,
        attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Width,
        multiplier: 0.7,
        constant: 0)
    self.view.addConstraint(equalWidthMult)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should change

```
str = "V:|[field1]-(==spacingV)-[field2]"
```

to

```
str = "V:|[field1]-(spacingV)-[field2]"
```

Comment: I have no idea why but now it works, with both syntax, thanks for the answer